# Apache commons email validator: allow plus character in e-mail

Tags: java, apache-commons, email-validation

using org.apache.commons.validator.routines.EmailValidator (1.7) for e-mail validation in Java.

In GMAIL a user is allowed to use `myname+anything@gmail.com` and it will go to `myname@gmail.com`. However, the `EmailValidator` does not allow the `+` character. I also tried replacing the `+` with `%2b` before validation but it also fails.

Any suggestions? Can I add an extra allowed character to my EmailValidator instance? Couldn't find this but guess I would need something like that.

Ps. I don't really want to go to custom regex for various reasons.

Comment: Judging from the source of `EmailValidator`, `+` is a valid character. Do you actually get `false`? Are you sure it's because of the `+`? Can you give a [mcve]?

Comment: That's weird. I 100% got false on the + character. Just removing this character gave true. Will test tomorrow again and share some more details. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Apache Commons EmailValidator **does** work with a plus sign.

```
import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.EmailValidator;

public class MapperMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String email = "john+Williams@ennui.co.za";
    
    EmailValidator emailValidator = EmailValidator.getInstance();
    
    
    System.out.println(emailValidator.isValid(email));

}

}
```

Outputs:

```
true
```

Comment: @RealSkeptic agree - fixed my answer.

Comment: That's weird. I 100% got false on the + character. Just removing this character gave true. Will test tomorrow again and share some more details. Thanks!

Comment: Tested again, my bad it actually works lol. Thanks!